# Why my Cordova project does't compile?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, visual-studio-cordova

I had this output: no more information and I don't know what's my error.

```
1>------ Rebuild All started: Project: Sac.Mobile, Configuration: Debug Android ------
1>  GeneratedJavascript=scripts\test.js;scripts\test.js.map;scripts\test.js;scripts\test.js.map
1>  C:\ECS\G4S Mobile Native\Sac.Mobile.Native.G4S\Sac.Mobile>call "C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\"\nodevars.bat 
1>  Your environment has been set up for using Node.js 0.10.33 (ia32) and npm.
1>  ------ Ensuring correct global installation of package from source package directory: C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 12.0\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\3DTNB2Y2.WZI\packages\vs-mda
========== Rebuild All: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

Does anybody have an idea?

Comment: Look into Error List window, it will list the error you encountered during build.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the latest version of VS Tools for Cordova (0.3.2 as of today), the error is listed in the Output or Error List window.

Otherwise go to `%APPDATA%\npm\node_modules\vs-mda` and edit `vs-cli.cmd` as follows:

```sh
node "%~dp0\app.js" %* > vs-mda.log 2> vs-mda-err.log
```

This will dump build logs to these files in your project folder.